# How to pass array to SOAP in PHP

Tags: php, soapserver

I would like pass this array by SOAP

```
'DeviceList'=>array('Devices'=>
        array(
           array('DeviceID'=>'teltec12347'),
           array('DeviceID'=>'teltec12347'),      
        )
    )
```

My SOAP server looks like:

```
 $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'DeviceList',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    '',
    '',
    array(
        'Devices'=> array('name'=>'Devices','type'=>'tns:DeviceArray')  
   )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'DeviceArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    'secuence',
    '',
    array(
        'DeviceID'     => array('name'=>'DeviceID','type'=>'xsd:string'), 
    ),
    'tns:DeviceList'
);
$server->register('shipmentDelivery',
    array(
    'ShopID'=>'xsd:int',
    'Password'=>'xsd:string',
    'ShipmentID'=>'xsd:string',
    'StartDate'=>'xsd:string',
    'EndDate'=>'xsd:string',
    'DeviceList'=>'tns:DeviceList'),
    array('return'=>'xsd:string'), 
    'urn:canaiwsdl',
    'urn:canaiwsdl#shipmentDelivery',
    'rpc',
    'encoded',
    'Hardware list'
);
```

I have got something like this. 
If I pass password or startDate everything is OK, but problems start when I would like pass array. How can I correctly pass array ?

Comment: Should secuence be sequence?

Comment: Yes, but this didn't resolve my problem.